# Counting of hours and days

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, malach-angel

The Torah states (Deuteronomy 18:10) “There shall not be found among you one who calculates times.”

There are however, "permissable" counting, such as the counting of the omer, the counting of

My question:
Is it permissable to count the hours of the day in order to determine angelic influences, and also use divine names to connect?

Can one count the days, for example by putting off serious decisions to a more "positive" influence is found?

Comment: Whose translation is that?

Comment: IIRC, that's got more to do with astrology and eschatology than arithmetic...

Comment: To me, it is really unclear what you are referring to, b/c that's not my understanding of any of the Hebrew words in the verse. I agree with @Cnsersmoit, and would add that if you can point to the specific Hebrew words that were translated that way, it would help immensely.

Comment: The translation is from an article by Rabbi Nissan Dubov, Director of Chabad. See link below for both the translation as well as the background to the question: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/361901/jewish/Angels-and-Mazalot.htm